# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType while trying to install muonic

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to install an interface that consists of a package and a python executable. I've already added the necessary modules, but now it gives me this error. The modules I need to use are:
python-scipy
python-matplotlib
python-numpy
python-qt4
python-serial
Does anybody know, what I can do to fix this? Thank you for your help

```
(venv) C:\Users\matsj\PycharmProjects\PythonPractice>easy_install --user muonic
WARNING: The user site-packages directory is disabled.
WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Searching for muonic
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/muonic/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/39/99ecbc20b1c30ebba260106c772cde0f15a6ff8f5d5f5b0e881004e558e3/muonic-3.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=6cf7e77337497fa62222c40245dc18f58350fb4cc
83573bffa47c4adb28d1154
Best match: muonic 3.0.0
Processing muonic-3.0.0.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\setup.cfg
Running muonic-3.0.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\egg-dist-tmp-_d0ztsor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\muonic\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\matsj\PycharmProjects\PythonPractice\venv\Scripts\easy_install.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 2343, in main
    setup(
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 161, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 424, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 692, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 718, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 903, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1171, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1157, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\users\matsj\pycharmprojects\pythonpractice\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2k4bma4_\muonic-3.0.0\muonic\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\matsj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, I would recommend using pip, rather than easy install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muonic, based on the [documentation](https://cosmiclabdesy.github.io/muonic/setup.html#prerequesitories), appears to be made for Linux, while you are trying to install it on a Windows machine. This is likely why the path variable is a nonetype and is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you, do you think I could run it on a Linux Virtual Machine, or do I need a separate computer with Linux installed?

Comment: @MatsSchröder A Linux virtual machine will work, but just to be safe, you should stick with the common distros, to avoid compatibility issues.